# Receiving "validators.map is not a function" error on my custom form control

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I created a family of components to use as form controls with the `ControlValueAccessor`.  When applying `formControlName`, `formGroupName` or `formGroupArray` to my components to pass in the form controls I get the error telling me

> validators.map is not a function

This is how my component is set up

```
@Component({
  selector: 'view-box-form-component',
  templateUrl: './view-box-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-box-form.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(()=>ViewBoxFormComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(()=>ViewBoxFormComponent)
    }
  ]
})

export class ViewBoxFormComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  ViewBoxFormData: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  public onTouched : ()=> void =()=>{};

  writeValue(val: any):void{ val && this.ViewBoxFormData.setValue(val, {emitEvent: false}); console.log(val); }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void{ this.ViewBoxFormData.valueChanges.subscribe(fn); console.log(fn); }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void{ this.onTouched = fn; }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void{ isDisabled ? this.ViewBoxFormData.disable() : this.ViewBoxFormData.enable(); }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    return this.ViewBoxFormData.valid ? null : {invalidForm:{valid: false, message: 'field invalid'}};
  }


}
```

and this is the template for that component

```
<section [formGroup]="ViewBoxFormData" class="text-control-section">


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> x: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="x" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> y: </p>
        <input type="y" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="y" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> width: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="width" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> height: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="height" />

    </label>


</section>
```

Inside the template to the parent component I implement the component like this

```
<form [formGroup]="SvgFormData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <view-box-form-component formGroupName="viewBox"></view-box-form-component>

</form>
```

I also have a couple other components I need to pass `FormArray`s into which I'm attempting to do with `formArrayName="someControl"`.  Instead of creating the form inside the components I generate it with functions based on JSON objects.  The function for creating the form group for the view box data looks like this.

```
export function CreateViewBoxForm(data?: ViewBoxParameters): FormGroup{
    return new FormGroup({
      x      :  new FormControl((data ? data.x      : ''), Validators.required),
      y      :  new FormControl((data ? data.y      : ''), Validators.required),
      width  :  new FormControl((data ? data.width  : ''), Validators.required),
      height :  new FormControl((data ? data.height : ''), Validators.required)
    }) as FormGroup;
  }
```

When I `console.log()` the completed form data everything is properly defined with all the proper values, I just can't figure out how to get them to pass into my components properly.  Dos anybody see what I'm doing wrong or if there's something more that I need to do to get this to work properly?

***UPDATE***

I decided to add a stackblitz of the entire mechanism so far so you guys can get a better idea for what I need to accomplish with my component structure.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9jtvy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll have to add `multi: true` to your `NG_VALIDATORS` token.

---

Also, it looks like your `ViewBoxFormComponent` is not a simple `FormControl`, because inside your component you have another `FormGroup` instance. IMO, this is not idiomatically correct.

`FormControlDirective`, `FormControlName`, `FormGroupName`, `FormArrayName`, `FormGroupDirective` are form-control based directives and they, when combined, form an `AbstractControlDirective` tree(because each one inherits from [`AbstractControlDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/abstract_control_directive.ts#L21)). These directives are the bridge between the the view layer(handled by `ControlValueAccessor`) and the model layer(handle by `AbstractControl` - the base class for `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, `FormArray`).

The root of such tree is `FormGroupDirective`(usually bound to a `form` element: `<form [formGroup]="formGroupInstance">`). With that in mind, your `AbstractControl` tree would look like this:

```
   FG <- [formGroup]="SvgFormData"
    |
    FC <- formGroupName="viewBox"
  / | \
 /  |  \
FC  FC  FC (height, width, x etc...)
```

The `FormControl` should have no descendants. In this case, because your custom component(`ViewBoxFormComponent`) creates another tree. This is **not wrong**, but with this approach, you'll have to properly handle the both trees in order to not get unexpected results.

The `FormGroup` instance bound to the `<section [formGroup]="ViewBoxFormData" class="text-control-section">` **will not** be registered as a descendant of `SvgFormData` because the `FormGroupDirective` does not behave like like `FormGroupName`:

#### [FormGroupDirective](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L83-L87)

```
constructor(
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) private _validators: any[],
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) private _asyncValidators: any[]) {
    super();
  }
```

#### [FormGroupName](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_name.ts#L87-L95)

```
  constructor(
      @Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parent: ControlContainer, // `ControlContainer` - token for `FormGroupDirective`/`FormGroupName`/`FormArrayName`
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: any[],
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: any[]) {
    super();
    this._parent = parent;
    this._validators = validators;
    this._asyncValidators = asyncValidators;
  }
```

If your custom component is not meant to contain a simple `FormControl` instance(it handles only a **standalone** `FormControl` instance with the help of `formControl` or `ngModel` directives), you should register it as descendant form group.
This can be achieved with this approach:

#### parent.component.ts

```js
// The shape of the form is defined in one place!
// The children must only comply with the shape defined here

this.SvgFormData = this.fb.group({
  ViewBoxFormData: this.fb.group({
   height: this.fb.control(''),
   width: this.fb.control(''),
  /* ... */
  })
})
```

#### parent.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="SvgFormData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <!-- this will be a child form group -->
    <view-box-form-component></view-box-form-component>

</form>
```

#### view-box-form-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'view-box-form-component',
  templateUrl: './view-box-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-box-form.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(()=>ViewBoxFormComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
 viewProviders: [
   { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }
 ]
})

export class ViewBoxFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}


  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is no need to provide `CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR` anymore, because the form's shape will be defined in only one place(i.e: the parent form container). All you have to do in your child form container is to provide the right paths that correlate to the shape defined in the parent:

#### view-box-form-component.component.html

```html
<section formGroupName="ViewBoxFormData" class="text-control-section">


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> x: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="x" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> y: </p>
        <input type="y" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="y" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> width: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="width" />

    </label>


    <label class="control-label">

        <p class="smallText"> height: </p>
        <input type="text" class="text-control smallText" formControlName="height" />

    </label>


</section>
```

What `viewProviders` does is to let you use a token(in this case `ControlContainer`) that is declared for the host element:

```
// FormGroupName

constructor (@Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parent: ControlContainer,) {}
```

*Note: the same approach can be applied to `FormArrayName`*.

You can find more about `AbstractControl` tree and how things work together in [A thorough exploration of Angular Forms](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/).

Comment: I see how this fits together, but what about if I have a component I use in more than one place that accesses a different `FormGroup` in each instance?  For example, I want to be able to add core attributes to the top level object that I want to be applied to all the SVG elements, then each SVG element has it's own attribute list that uses the same component to iterate, add and delete them.  How could I use this method to make that component sync to the proper `FormGroup` in each instance?

Comment: I added a stackblitz to my question so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have a closer look in a few hours.

Comment: @Optiq I had a look and I'm not sure I fully understood the context, but if you want to have more control on which dependency to use, you can use, instead of `useExisting`, `useFactory: fn` with `deps:[Injector]`. With the help of the **Injector** (which is a map object internally, if I'm not wrong), you get any dep you want.